# Clarification of Generalizing and Overfitting

Tags: machine-learning

To get to clarification of "generalizing" and "overfitting" I first must state the following: We have a robot, it makes guesses, and the way we know what guesses to keep is by if the received sensory input matches pre-installed senses that keep it alive/producing. The analog to my terms are training/test data and guessing and "?", correct? So now, it ends up saving better actions to pick up food, then a fork, if the actions are in their teen-age stage then they generalize and can pick up both food and a fork whereas if they are overfit then it only picks up a fork with too much precision. Is that what generalizing and overfit mean?

Comment: 1. One question per question, please.  I've edited out the second question - you can post it separately. 2. I don't know what you mean by "saved actions" and "triggers".  Generalizing and overfitting is used in the machine learning for arbitrary supervised classification tasks (where there's no notion of "saved actions" or "triggers").  3. What research have you done?  Have you read the discussion of these topics in standard textbooks/tutorials?  What specifically did you find confusing? There are many resources on machine learning, and there'd be little point in repeating standard resources.

Comment: By triggers and saved actions I mean - the robot guesses, sensory input checks if matches preinstalled images/ect, and if does, saves guessed actions. The robot's saved actions can get better, so - does generalizing mean the robot's saved actions are good at two tasks, otherwise if it was a perfect hand movement it'd ONLY ex. pick up the food but not the fork and is overfit~

Comment: Please edit the question to include all information needed to understand it.  Don't just leave clarifications in comments -- comments are intended to help you improve your question.  We want the question to stand alone, so people don't need to read the comments.  (Also, comments are intended as transitory and can disappear at any time.)  Provide all context and background needed to understand what youa re asking.  (For instance, I don't know what "sensory input checks if..." means: sensory input isn't an active entity that can do stuff.)

Comment: Ok I'm done editing it.

Answer (score 2):

No not exactly.

To be precise:

Generalisation means the ability of a machine-learning algorithm/device to match  / process data it **has not seen before (but are in the domain of the problem)**, correctly.

Overfitting, is that state of learning where the algorithm is very tightly bound to the data it has seen (trained, tested) that **it cannot generalise well to data not seen before (but are in the domain of the problem)**.

So in this sense these are inter-related.

If you can clarify how the above relate to your use-case i can expand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really.

### Generalization

Generalization means the ability to generalize from the training data to new situations you've never seen before.  For example, suppose the robot has the following past experience:

- On Monday, it saw a plate of food and a cup of water on the table; it picked up a fork, and got a positive reward.
- On Tuesday, it saw a plate of food and a newspaper on the table; it picked up a fork, and got a positive reward.
- On Wednesday, it saw a newspaper and a bill on the table; it picked up a fork, and got no reward.
- On Thursday, it saw a bill and a plate of food on the table; it picked up a fork, and got a positive reward.

A machine learning algorithm might learn the rule "If you saw a plate of food on the table, pick up the fork."  If it does, then (intuitively) we'd say it has generalized well.

For instance, suppose on Friday it sees a plate of food and a mosquito on the table, and based on the rule it has learned, it picks up the food.  That would count as an example of generalization, because it has figured out what to do in a situation it hasn't seen before.

### Overfitting

Overfitting means a failure to generalize from the training data: it means the machine learning algorithm has learned something overly specific, that is overly specific to the training data, often to the point of finding spurious "patterns" that don't apply to future data.  This typically causes future predictions to be wrong.

For example, suppose the robot has the following past experience:

- On Monday, it saw a plate of food on the table, it saw that the digital clock on the wall was showing 7:57, and it saw out the window that the weather was cloudy; it picked up a fork, and got a positive reward.
- On Tuesday, it saw a plate of food on the table, the clock showing 8:01, and sunny weather out the window; it picked up a fork, and got a positive reward.
- On Wednesday, it saw a newspaper on the table, the clock showing 7:49, and rain out the window; it picked up a fork, and got no reward.
- On Thursday, it saw a plate of food on the table, the clock showing 5:42, and the weather was overcast; it picked up a fork, and got a positive reward.

Now suppose that the machine learning algorithm learns the rule "If you see a plate of food on the table and either it's sunny or you see the digit 5 somewhere on the clock's display, then pick up the fork".  That would be a case of overfitting: it has learned a spurious, overly specific pattern, one that is too closely based on the points in the training set.  In real life, the weather and the digits showing on the digital clock should be irrelevant to the decision of whether to pick up a fork.

Comment: In your first fork example, how is the robot generalizing if it's only picking up the fork only when it sees a fork (don't matter if newspaper/mosquito was there or not, if was=no pick up), I thought my explanation of being able to grasp a fork and a banana was generalizing whereas overly precise fingers are overfit and only pick up a fork......***>>>Next, I now understand it'd pick up a fork when sees a digit 5 anywhere, it'd be the initiater just like seeing a fork is, but what if it's head was only staring at a clock when it got its food trigger by picking up a fork - only 1 initializer!

Comment: @FriendlyPerson44, I've edited to add one more paragraph to the end of the "Generalization" section, to explain how this is generalization.  take a look at it.

Comment: Part2: So what if we hope it's staring at the fork when it guesses actions and saves them when gets reward? And only keep those moment iniaters? That way it could get better while never being able to turn its head fast enough to see other things (short window time).

Comment: There are many machine learning textbooks that have a good explanation of overfitting and generalization.  My advice is to spend some quality time doing self-study with those textbooks, and learning the meaning of those terms in standard contexts, before trying to see how they apply to your ideas for a robot AI.  The pattern I see from your series of comments and questions is that you don't yet grasp the fundamentals -- so you'd probably benefit from spending some time studying the fundamentals, rather than trying to reason from first principles about robots based on your real-life experience.

Comment: Yes I seen the edit, my reply is still the same...

Comment: I understood what you said, make sure to read through my part1(bottom of part1) & part2 comments.

Comment: To clarify my point I just said --- Your "generalizing" robot vs my "overfit" robot both can get overfit because they both can: Make a guess, stare at a clock, get a reward by guessed action, then save the action and it'll be done when sees a clock. Both of ours can "gain" the wrong que to do the action.